# Ubuntu 16 doesn't power off completely my HP

Tags: shutdown

Well, this is strange. When i shut down my computer. It freezes on *power down*!!

Here is an example with some screenshots : [image]

[image]

At the end, i have to long press the power off button. I have no other solution. Any help please??

**UPDATE** : Here is Syslog https://file.io/8YFMUR

Comment: Please provide syslog and dmesg

Comment: dmesg is command that prints or control the kernel ring buffer, but  It is being reinitialized after each power on !!

Comment: I have the syslog where do you want me to look @Ashu ? please

Comment: you can put into some pastebin etc....

Comment: updated my question with what you asked ... :)